# Magento2 CMSBlock API contains variables. How to replace?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, cms-block

I Have a **magento2 EE** with a headless implementation. Hence I am using the `rest/V1/cmsBlock/<id>` to fetch the content which is added by admin (WYSIWYG).

Problem:

I see the output like :

```
<response>
    <id>2</id>
    <identifier>pirates</identifier>
    <title>Pirates are Back!</title>
    <content>
        <h2><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/the-Pirates-of-the-Caribbean--172-Jack-Sparrow.jpg"}}" alt="Pirates are Back" width="387" height="259" /></h2>
    </content>
    <creation_time>2017-01-09 16:03:20</creation_time>
    <update_time>2017-01-09 16:07:12</update_time>
    <active>true</active>
</response>
```

Now my front-end does not understand

```
{{media url="wysiwyg/the-Pirates-of-the-Caribbean-Pop-172-Jack-Sparrow.jpg"}}
```

So now, how do I get the actual URL of the image instead of the variable? As a part of the XML response itself without overriding the API.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a data post-processor in your headless client that can resolve directives. It may be difficult to support all possible types, but depending on what you need to support, it might be pretty simple. For this example, you could use the [`/rest/V1/store/storeConfigs` endpoint](https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/storestoreConfigs#operation/GetV1StoreStoreConfigs) to retrieve the `media_base_url`. Then you can resolve the full media URL and replace it into the CMS content.

[image: REST doc for store/storeConfigs]